# What does SHCONTF_FLATLIST actually mean in Shell folder enumeration?

Tags: windows-shell

The documentation is vague, at least: "[Enumerate items as a simple list even if the folder itself is not structured in that way.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_shcontf)" Ok, and what is this supposed to mean? Is it a synonym of "recursively"? If I have a folder with subfolders, should I list all children on all levels as if my main folder contained them directly? That's not how Shell works, as it seems - if I do the above in a shell namespace extension, the Shell displays all items that the extension has returned. Obviously, the flag is intended to do something different – but what?

Comment: Ignore it. It's a leftover from an early beta of Windows Vista that isn't used any more. I'll update the docs.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you very much! I really didn't expect any answer, and that was a surprise :)